# GitLab: How to disable automatic startup?

Tags: debian, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

I have not found a way to disable the automatic startup and it ends up using too much RAM when I'm not using.

The init files are not inside /etc/init or init.d.

I try `update-rc.d gitlab remove` and no results.

I am using GitLab 8.5.4 in Debian 8.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have a file `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf` ?

Comment: Thank for answer. No. I do not have any file starting with "gi" in /etc/init or init.d.

Comment: I install with this tutorial: https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/install - Manual, deb section

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Problem is solved!

I contacted the `GitLab` by their official page on Facebook and here is the answer.
I am using GitLab in a Desktop and it was using ~700MB.
If you too want turn off GitLab on startup, just execute in a terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable gitlab-runsvdir.service
```

Comment: This seemed to undo itself some time down the line, possibly after an update.

Comment: As one might guess, re-enable GitLab using `sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir.service`.

Comment: This is really not ideal, as this disabled the ``gitlab-ctl`` command completely. There has to be a way to disable auto booting without disabling the ctl command as well, requiring the restoration of the service before being able to work with gitlab again.